# transferring chat history from phone app to computer

Tags: apps, history, transfer

I'm about to buy my first smartphone. I'm considering one with a Windows OS.

At the risk of sounding ignorant - is it possible to transfer chat history (and other such data) from the GTalk/Skype/Facebook app on one's phone, to the computer?

If so, how does one go about it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

These don't need to transfer actually. Take the facebook app for example: anytime you chat with someone through your phone, it will automatically show on your computer when you log in to facebook in your messages. This should be the same across all three apps.

Comment: How about SMS chats? I've known people that have wanted to save their chat messages when moving from one phone to another.

Comment: You mean like texts, or facebook chat texts? The facebook chat 'texts' do transfer to facebook when you log on to the computer. This is because they actually go through the internet and is the same thing as chatting on the computer, it just isn't through an app. The windows phone is just awesome enough to do it in the sms area.

Comment: No, just plain old text messages, non-Facebook, non anything else.

Comment: Nope not unless you back up your current state and flash that to another phone.. way more hassle than it's worth